# Erro de sintaxe no comando sql

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin

Estou com um possível problema na sintaxe do sql no meu código

```
 if (tbCPF.Text != "" && tbNome.Text != "" && tbEndereco.Text != "" && tbNumero.Text != "" && tbBairro.Text != "" && tbCEP.Text != "" && tbCidade.Text != "" && tbRG.Text != "" && tbAumento.Text != "" && cbCargo.Text != "")
            {
                cmd = new MySqlCommand("update FUNCIONARIO set CPF_FUNCIONARIO=@CPF, NOME_FUNCIONARIO=@NOME, RG_FUNCIONARIO=@RG ENDEREÇO_FUNCIONARIO=@ENDERECO, NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO=@NUMERO, BAIRRO_FUNCIONARIO=@BAIRRO, CEP_FUNCIONARIO=@CEP, CIDADE_FUNCIONARIO=@CIDADE, ID_CARGO=@CARGO, AUMENTO_FUNCIONARIO=@AUMENTO where CPF_FUNCIONARIO=@ID", con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CPF", tbCPF.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOME", tbNome.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RG", tbRG.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENDERECO", tbEndereco.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMERO", tbNumero.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BAIRRO", tbBairro.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEP", tbCEP.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIDADE", tbCidade.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARGO", cbCargo.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AUMENTO", tbAumento.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Atualizado com sucesso");
                con.Close();
                DisplayData();
                ClearData();
                btnSalvar.Text = "Salvar";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Por favor preencha todos os campos");
            }
```

ao executar ele me exibe o seguinte erro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já verifiquei o comando sql, e esta correto, pode ser outra coisa que esta originando o erro mas eu não sei, aonde esta errado, por favor me ajudem!
(estou usando o phpMyAdmin da locaweb)

Comment: NUNCA utilize caracteres especiais em variáveis, colunas do banco dentre outros.. eu particularmente utilizo em inglês

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu comando `SQL` está com erro de sintaxe entre os campos RG e Endereço (está faltando vírgula entre os campos). Segue abaixo o comando alterado:

```
UPDATE FUNCIONARIO 
   SET CPF_FUNCIONARIO=@CPF,
       NOME_FUNCIONARIO=@NOME,
       RG_FUNCIONARIO=@RG,
       ENDEREÇO_FUNCIONARIO=@ENDERECO,
       NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO=@NUMERO,
       BAIRRO_FUNCIONARIO=@BAIRRO,
       CEP_FUNCIONARIO=@CEP,
       CIDADE_FUNCIONARIO=@CIDADE,
       ID_CARGO=@CARGO,
       AUMENTO_FUNCIONARIO=@AUMENTO 
 WHERE CPF_FUNCIONARIO=@ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando uma virgula entre

```
RG_FUNCIONARIO=@RG ENDEREÇO_FUNCIONARIO=@ENDERECO
                  ^
```